# Не могу присвоить указателю указатель

Tags: c++

Есть функция `vertical_2d_shift`. Принимает двумерный массив (в виде указателя на указатель) и сдвигает его строчки циклически на 1 вниз.

Принцип работы - создаю ещё один двумерный массив. Потом говорю, что указатель на первую строку нового массива это указатель на последнюю старого, указатель на 1-ю есть указатель на 0 старого и так далее. А потом просто говорю, что новый массив теперь вместо старого.

```
template<typename T>
T** make_2d_array(int n, int m) {
    T** arr = (T**)malloc(n * sizeof(T*));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = (T*)malloc(m * sizeof(T));
    }
    return arr;
}

template<typename T>
void vertical_2d_shift(T** arr, int n, int m) {

    T** new_arr = make_2d_array<T>(n, m);

    new_arr[0] = arr[n - 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        new_arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }

    arr = new_arr;
    //for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //    arr[i] = new_arr[i];
    //}
}
```

Этот код почему-то не работает. То есть `arr` не меняется и никакого циклического сдвига не происходит. Но если я закомментирую `arr = new_arr;` и раскомментирую цикл, что после него, всё сработает. Но почему?

Почему я не могу просто подменить указатель одного двумерного массива на указатель другого и так будто подменить сам массив? Я даже выводил адрес `arr` до и после присвоения - ничего не меняется.

И в то же самое время, когда я делаю то же самое не для двумерного массива**, а для одномерного*, проблем не возникает (я как минимум про тот for).

Comment: Утечки памяти Вас сейчас не волнуют?

Comment: @Igor ещё как волнуют, но я их заметил уже только когда написал вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение:

```
template<typename T>
void vertical_2d_shift(T** &arr, int n, int m) {
```

чтобы менять массив его надо передавать в функцию по ссылке

Еще одна ошибка в коде - вы не удаляете старый массив в самом конце и в итоге программа течет

Ну и самое главное - зачем так сложно - зачем вообще создавать новый массив, когда вы можете в старом массиве просто изменить циклически указатели

```
template<typename T>
void vertical_2d_shift(T** arr, int n, int m) {

    T* tmp = arr[n - 1];

    for(int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {        
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    }

    arr[0] = tmp;
 }
```

Comment: По моему, надо открывать чемпионат по скоростным ответам на вопросы по C++. и... у нас уже есть кандидат в чемпионы!

Comment: @Zhihar Действительно. Спасибо большое, так правда намного легче. Но в любом случае, можете, пожалуйста, поподробнее пояснить насчёт ссылки? Почему она нам нужна? Разве то, что мы аргументом принимаем указатель, не значит, что мы уже можем по ссылке менять данные как только не захочется? И почему тогда при присвоении без ссылки у меня не вылетела ошибка?

Comment: @witaway, ну давайте порассуждать - если вы передаете число `int` - вы его изменить не сможете, только если передадите `int&` или `int*` (тогда вызов функции будет `func(&value)`), если вы передаете массив int* - вы его (не содержимое, а именно сам объект) изменить не можете, только `int* &` или `int**` (тогда вызов функции будет `func(&arr)`), для двухмерного массива та же логика - или передаете `int** &` или `int***`. Чтобы менять внешний объект из функции (заменить один объект на другой) вам нужна или ссылка на объект или указатель на объект - у вас двухмерный массив, т.е. T** dim